# VS Code and Java Outline: Inherited Fields/Methods of a Class?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Is there a way for VS code to display fields/methods inherited from a super class?

I have this base class:

```
public abstract class BaseModel {

  @Transient
  public String SEQUENCE_NAME;

  @Id
  public long id;

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
```

and it's child class

```
public class NavigationMenuItem extends BaseModel {

  private String text;
  private String path;

  public NavigationMenuItem(String text, String path) {
    SEQUENCE_NAME = "navigation_menu_item_sequence";
    this.setText(text);
    this.setPath(path);
  }

  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  public String getPath() {
    return path;
  }

  public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
  }



}
```

in VS Code Java Outline pane, it's only showing fields/methods from `NavigationMenuItem` .

Is there a way to also include the parent fields/methods?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. Inherited field are typically never shown in an outline/structure view from my experience with Eclipse, Netbeans & IntelliJ. Maybe there's a plugin for what you need. Try Software Recommendation Stack Exchange. This also seems relevant: [GitHub Issue request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84060)

Comment: in Eclipse there is an arrow in the left gutter that flags an inherited method.